# RestKit Basic K-V Mapping

Tags: restkit-0.20

I have a JSON payload that is being returned from my server and is structured like this:

`{"users":[users]}`

Using a simple RKObjectMapping and RKResponseDescriptor, I'm able to successfully map this JSON into a collection of User objects when I use getObjectsAtPath, but now I'd like to make a slight modification to the JSON server-side.  Namely, I'd like to add a key-path

`{"users":[users], "more":true}`

where the key-path "more" indicates whether there are more users to load that are not included in the "users" array.  The problem I'm having is that I can't find a simple way to access the value of this "more" key-path.  Ideally, I'd like to define a Mapping and Response Descriptor that map "more" into a BOOL (or NSNumber), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.  Adding a mapping like

`RKObjectMapping *moreMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSNumber class]]`

with ResponseDescriptor

`[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:moreMapping                                                                                                 pathPattern:pathPattern

keyPath:@"more"                                                                             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];`

Doesn't do the trick.  Ultimately, in the success block of getObjects, I'd like my RKMappingResult to be structured like so:

`@{@"users":[users], @"more":1}`

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

RestKit is based around mapping data into objects, not to objects in the way you're after. The closest you can get is to map the `true` into an `NSNumber` inside a dictionary or array. Try:

```
RKObjectMapping *moreMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[moreMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"more"]];
```